# Count user actions using two different MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, pivot

I have two tables; `users` and `texts`.

`users` keeps the user information, such as username, password, etc.

`texts` keeps some texts and some additional columns like added_from, updated_from, deleted_from so when a user makes a specific action, his username is written in the texts record in related column (if I update the text my username is written in updated_from column).

I want to count all user actions according to columns added_from, updated_from, deleted_from and the result has to be something like

```
Username | Added | Updated | Deleted
 ========|=======|=========|======
  user_1 |     1 |       9 |       0
  user_2 |     5 |       9 |       2
```

The query i'm trying to use is

```
SELECT t.added_from,
COUNT(t.added_from) AS Added,
COUNT(t.updated_from) AS Updated
FROM users u, texts t
WHERE u.username = t.added_from
GROUP BY u.username ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

but it shows results only for the first username that finds in texts.
I want to print all usernames from users table and count all their actions depending on how many times their username is shown in columns added, updated or deleted

Comment: Why does user_1 appear twice?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry your edit appears to remove useful information (point 3 in the accepted answer of your link, 'best efforts to date'). Was this intentional?

Comment: @JobCurtis - Oh, I see what you mean. Oops. Fixed

Comment: Why does user_1 appear twice? >>> Corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want conditional aggregation. The logic should look like:

```
select
    u.username,
    sum(u.username = t.added_from)   added,
    sum(u.username = t.updated_from) updated,
    sum(u.username = t.deleted_from) deleted
from users u
inner join texts t 
    on u.username in (t.added_from, t.updated_from, t.deleted_from)
group by u.username
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It shows correct results but counts actions made only by users that their username exists in any of these 3 columns in texts table. Is it possible to show all users from users table and count 0 if they never made an action?

Comment: @akis_m: just change the `inner join` to a `left join`.

Comment: Its magic (i'm noob to joins). Thanks again. It works perfectly.